# How to get the update and delete endpoints to function properly in my React App?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, fetch, mern

So I have a simple **React CRUD** application that has a **Node/Express** backend and is using **MongoDB** for a database. I can make my `GET` request using **fetch** which is displaying all my data from the backend. And I can create a new record in my database using `POST` but I cannot `PUT` and `DELETE`.

First here is my controller and routes from the backend.

```js
/*
  controllers
*/
const updateStudent = (req, res) => {
  // Validate Request
  if (!req.body.email) {
    return res.status(400).send({
      message: "This student is not enrolled",
    });
  }
  Student.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.params.id, {
        $set: req.body,
      }, {
        new: true
      }
    )
    .then((student) => {
      if (!student) {
        return res.status(404).send({
          message: "Student not found with Student ID " + req.params.studentId,
        });
      }
      res.send(student);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      if (err.kind === "ObjectId") {
        return res.status(404).send({
          message: "Student not found with Student ID " + req.params.studentId,
        });
      }
      return res.status(500).send({
        message: "Error updating note with Student ID " + req.params.studentId,
      });
    });
};

const deleteStudent = (req, res) => {
  Student.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.send("Deleted successfully!");
  });
};

/*
  routes
*/

router.put("/students/:id", updateStudent);
router.delete("/students/:id", deleteStudent);
```

Now I have tested this in `Postman` and it works.

here is the data I am getting:

```js
[{
    "_id": "5ea5b23f16d306c66835d470",
    "fname": "John",
    "lname": "Doe",
    "email": "johndoe@doe.com",
    "phone": "123-789-0456",
    "studentId": "aiw3sgspj",
    "street1": "1001 Doe St",
    "street2": "Apt. 105",
    "city": "Washington",
    "state": "DC",
    "zip": 20010,
    "createdAt": "2020-04-26T16:09:35.641Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-04-26T16:09:35.641Z"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ea5b27116d306c66835d471",
    "fname": "Jane",
    "lname": "Did",
    "email": "johndoe@did.com",
    "phone": "789-123-4560",
    "studentId": "n5bsm5mzx",
    "street1": "1001 Did St",
    "street2": "Apt. 105",
    "city": "Washington",
    "state": "DC",
    "zip": 20010,
    "createdAt": "2020-04-26T16:10:25.050Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-04-26T16:10:25.050Z"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ea5b2b016d306c66835d472",
    "fname": "Jim",
    "lname": "Done",
    "email": "jdone@done.com",
    "phone": "456-789-0231",
    "studentId": "h7ofl7eue",
    "street1": "1001 Done St",
    "street2": "Apt. 105",
    "city": "Washington",
    "state": "DC",
    "zip": 20010,
    "createdAt": "2020-04-26T16:11:28.797Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-04-26T16:11:28.797Z"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ea5b2d916d306c66835d473",
    "fname": "Jll",
    "lname": "Do",
    "email": "jdo@do.com",
    "phone": "123-456-7890",
    "studentId": "goentqjix",
    "street1": "1001 Do St",
    "street2": "Apt. 105",
    "city": "Washington",
    "state": "DC",
    "zip": 20010,
    "createdAt": "2020-04-26T16:12:09.236Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-04-26T16:12:09.236Z"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ea5b7b8d78372d84f0e54f7",
    "fname": "Joe",
    "lname": "Dare",
    "email": "joedare@dare.com",
    "phone": "456-234-6789",
    "studentId": "x6kj7w05-",
    "street1": "1001 Dare St.",
    "street2": "Apt. 106",
    "city": "Washington",
    "state": "DC",
    "zip": 20010,
    "createdAt": "2020-04-26T16:32:56.465Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-04-26T16:32:56.465Z"
  }
]
```

Here is where my update is being called in my **React** app

```js
submitFormEdit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  fetch(`http://localhost:8096/api/students/`, {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        id: this.state.id,
        fname: this.state.fname,
        lname: this.state.lname,
        email: this.state.email,
        phone: this.state.phone,
        street1: this.state.street1,
        street2: this.state.street2,
        city: this.state.city,
        state: this.state.state,
        zip: this.state.zip,
        gpa: this.state.gpa,
      }),
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((item) => {
      if (Array.isArray(item)) {
        // console.log(item[0])
        this.props.updateState(item[0]);
        this.props.toggle();
      } else {
        console.log("failure");
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

and here is my delete call

```js
deleteItem = (id) => {
  let confirmDelete = window.confirm("Delete item forever?");
  if (confirmDelete) {
    fetch("http://localhost:8096/api/students", {
        method: "DELETE",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          id,
        }),
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((item) => {
        this.props.deleteItemFromState(id);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change fetch methods to uppercase, that might work for you. method: "delete", should be replaced by method:"DELETE", and same for put as well.

Comment: Are you getting any errors. Look for appropriate call in browser tab and start debugging then.

Answer (score 0):

The request url is not properly formated in React code it should be

```
fetch("http://localhost:8096/api/students/"+id
```

because you are accessing the id from req.params.id in node.js, donot put it in the body

Comment: That does not work nor does ``http://localhost:8096/api/students/${id}``

Answer (score 0):

So the delete code should look like this:

```js
deleteItem = (id) => {
  let confirmDelete = window.confirm("Delete item forever?");
  if (confirmDelete) {
    fetch(`http://localhost:8096/api/students/${id}`, {
        method: "DELETE",
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(() => {
        this.props.deleteItemFromState(id);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }
};
```

I removed the **item** parameter from the **promise** and did add the `id` to the endpoint

And the update code should look like this

```js
submitFormEdit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const {
    item
  } = this.props;
  fetch(`http://localhost:8096/api/students/${item._id}`, {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(this.state),
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((item) => {
      if (item) {
        this.props.updateState(item);
        this.props.toggle();
      } else {
        console.log("failure");
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

The `Array.isArray(item)` was incorrect since I was not updating an array but an **object**